# How to use the Android component Xamarin.InAppBilling with "link all assemblies" in release mode?

Tags: android, linker, in-app-purchase, xamarin, in-app-billing

The Xamarin component [Xamarin.InAppBilling](http://components.xamarin.com/view/xamarin.inappbilling) can't retrieve any products via `serviceConnection.BillingHandler.QueryInventoryAsync` when using the linker behavior "*Link all assemblies*" (Project Options -> Android Build -> Linker).

You can easily reproduce this problem by changing the link behaviour option in the components own sample project. Is it possible to use `[Preserve]` attribute or similar to fix this? I would really like to minimize the apk's final size as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit late but I think it might be helpfully...

A easy solution is to add a [Custom Linker Configuration](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/custom_linking/) with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<linker>
    <assembly fullname="Xamarin.InAppBilling">
        <namespace fullname="Xamarin.InAppBilling" />
    </assembly>
</linker>
```

then the linker skips the Xamarin.InAppBilling assably and it works.